# How to install LSOF in AIX

Tags: aix, lsof

I wanna install LSOF in AIX.

I've download the program from https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/reg/pick.do?source=aixbp&lang=en_US.

after I unzip the tar file, I don't get readme or installation guide file.

This is the first time I use Unix operation system, can you help to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make this happen.  Here is what I did:

```
[:/home/jfarnswo/installer/lsof_aix61_4.77] $ installp -l -d .
  Fileset Name                Level                     I/U Q Content
  ====================================================================
  lsof.base                   6.1.0.4700                 I  N usr,root
#   List Of Open Files

  lsof.license                6.1.0.4700                 I  N usr
#   List Of Open Files

  lsof.man.en_US              6.1.0.4700                 I  N usr
#   List Of Open Files Documentation - U.S. English

[:/home/jfarnswo/installer/lsof_aix61_4.77] $ installp -a -c -d . lsof
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                    Pre-installation Verification...
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Verifying selections...done
Verifying requisites...done
Results...

SUCCESSES
---------
  Filesets listed in this section passed pre-installation verification
  and will be installed.

  Selected Filesets
  -----------------
  lsof.base 6.1.0.4700                        # List Of Open Files
  lsof.license 6.1.0.4700                     # List Of Open Files
  lsof.man.en_US 6.1.0.4700                   # List Of Open Files Documenta...

  << End of Success Section >>

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                   BUILDDATE Verification ...
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Verifying build dates...done
FILESET STATISTICS
------------------
    3  Selected to be installed, of which:
        3  Passed pre-installation verification
  ----
    3  Total to be installed

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                         Installing Software...
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

installp:  APPLYING software for:
        lsof.man.en_US 6.1.0.4700


. . . . . << Copyright notice for lsof.man.en_US >> . . . . . . .
 Licensed Materials - Property of IBM

 5765G0382
   Copyright International Business Machines Corp. 2007, 2009.

 All rights reserved.
 US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or disclosure
 restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
. . . . . << End of copyright notice for lsof.man.en_US >>. . . .

Filesets processed:  1 of 3  (Total time:  6 secs).

installp:  APPLYING software for:
        lsof.license 6.1.0.4700


. . . . . << Copyright notice for lsof.license >> . . . . . . .
 Licensed Materials - Property of IBM

 5765G0382
   Copyright International Business Machines Corp. 2008, 2009.

 All rights reserved.
 US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or disclosure
 restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
. . . . . << End of copyright notice for lsof.license >>. . . .

Filesets processed:  2 of 3  (Total time:  7 secs).

installp:  APPLYING software for:
        lsof.base 6.1.0.4700


. . . . . << Copyright notice for lsof.base >> . . . . . . .
 Licensed Materials - Property of IBM

 5765G0382
   Copyright International Business Machines Corp. 2007, 2009.
   Copyright Free Software Foundation, Inc., 1985, 1989-1993, 1995-1998, 2000.
   Copyright Purdue Research Foundation, West Lafayette, Indiana, 1994

 All rights reserved.
 US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or disclosure
 restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
. . . . . << End of copyright notice for lsof.base >>. . . .

Successfully updated the Kernel Authorization Table.
Successfully updated the Kernel Role Table.
Successfully updated the Kernel Command Table.
Successfully updated the Kernel Device Table.
Finished processing all filesets.  (Total time:  8 secs).

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
                                Summaries:
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Installation Summary
--------------------
Name                        Level           Part        Event       Result
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lsof.man.en_US              6.1.0.4700      USR         APPLY       SUCCESS
lsof.license                6.1.0.4700      USR         APPLY       SUCCESS
lsof.base                   6.1.0.4700      USR         APPLY       SUCCESS
lsof.base                   6.1.0.4700      ROOT        APPLY       SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always go inside of the untar'd directory and do `smitty installp`. When prompted for install source, type `.` and then navigate through the screens.

Note that I usually set "accept license agreements" to "yes".

Answer (score 0):

What files do you see?

If it's something like

```
Change_log.txt
lsof.base
lsof.license
lsof.man.en_US
```

then I think you need to run installp.

Try something like

```
installp -l -d .
installp -a -c -d .
```

(assuming you are in the unzipped lsof directory, otherwise change the period/dot symbol to the name of the directory that you unzipped it to)

It's been a long time since I used AIX, so please check if I am right.  Documentation is available by running "man installp", or by visiting this link. http://www.regatta.cmc.msu.ru/doc/usr/share/man/info/ru_RU/a_doc_lib/cmds/aixcmds3/installp.htm